# void* указатель из std::any

Tags: c++

Как можно получить void* указатель из std::any
Я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное:

```
...
std::any& value = ...
...
} else if (value.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
...
} else {
Parent* obj;
If (obj = dynamic_cast<Parent*>(value.getPointer) {
obj->something();
...
} else {
logE("can't convert value:" << value.type().name();
}
}
...
```

Comment: Даже если вы получите `void *`, передать его в `dynamic_cast` не получится. Вообще наличие `any`, `typeid` и `dynamic_cast` в одном месте очень подозрительно.

Comment: Мне просто надо проверить наследует-ли значение в `any` класс `Parent` и в случае успеха выполнить его метод

Comment: Может вам `std::any_cast` нужен?

Comment: У меня есть несколько классов, наследуемых от `Parent`, я не хочу делать проверку для каждого из них. `any_cast` не катит. Он же просто сверяет `type_id` и кастит в нужный тип. Он же не downcast-ит? Да и вроде нельзя проверить `type_id` на наследование